# how to embed currency converter on my website

Tags: converters, currency

The base currency of my website is USD, and I want that when users enter a particular amount of USD (say 10 USD), it gets converted into the local currency (say INR) as per the prevalent forex rate. There are many online currency converters available that converts the currency values. But I want a solution wherein users are just required to enter the amount in USD and it changes to its respective INR value and they can proceed with the INR amount for transactions. In short I want a solution where converted currency values are returned for use on my webpages. I tried using the following code on my website but it just changes the USD amount to INR and displays it. I want to use the displayed results for proceeding further with the transactions. Anyone please help. Thanks in advance.

```
<div id="powerd"><a href="http://www.transfermate.com/" target="_blank" id="tm_add146" class="tm_add146">Powered by TransferMate</a></div><script src="https://www.transfermate.com/en/exchange_rates_api.asp?csel=USD,INR&cshort=" type="text/javascript"></script><noscript><br/><span style="color: red;">Please enable your javascript.</span></noscript>
```

Comment: How about try your hands on some API, and then configure it according to your requirement?
For example, when you successfully convert the currency, store in some variable which you can use in further transaction. (play and observe with some API)

Comment: Please elaborate your answer with some example.

Comment: For example this : http://jsonrates.com/
You can use this API to perform the conversion.

To use an API, you can refer to http://readwrite.com/2013/09/19/api-defined and 
http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/47130/how-do-i-use-an-api